# Is it possible to access the priority fee in a contract?

Tags: solidity, eip-1559

I was discussing on twitter that mega NFT drops can self-regulate their affect on the network by setting an adjustable gas cap within the contract such as:

`require(tx.gasPrice < gasCap, "Gas price too damn high!");`

Another dev mentioned this would have been doable except that now with EIP-1559 in play, we need to be concerned about the priority fee, so this strategy may not work.

Is there any way to see what the priority fee is on a contract's tx?

Comment: no, the transaction don't keep this record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Priority Fee for a particular transaction is simply the difference between the gas price paid by the sender and the basefee for the particular block. Read more about that [here](https://www.blocknative.com/blog/eip-1559-fees)

With this in mind, the priority fee (or miner's tip) can be computed in a contract as follows -

```
uint minersTip = tx.gasprice - block.basefee;
```

FYI [here](https://github.com/ruvaag/gas-stamped-nft) is my implementation of a gas-capped NFT drop from sometime back, which sounds pretty similar to what you're referring to. This implementation limits the miner tip by capping the percentage of gas fees that can be paid as the miner's tip.